# How to make the latest chat above others?

Tags: android

I'm working on a chat app, how can I make the latest chat come above others? Here in the image, the last message received was by Wejdan, but as you can see it is still on the bottom not on the top of other chats.

[image]

I saved every message with its timeStamp & isSeen value like below:
[image]

I know it has something to do with the timeStamp but I don't know how to implement it. Here is my code for sending a message:

```
private void sendMessage (final String sender, final String receiver, String message){
        final String timeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("sender", sender);
        hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
        hashMap.put("message", message);
        hashMap.put("isseen", false);
        hashMap.put("time", timeStamp);
        reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
        final DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
                .child(fUser.getUid()).child(userid);
        chatRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(!snapshot.exists()){
                    chatRef.child("id").setValue(userid);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
        final DatabaseReference chatRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
                .child(receiver).child(fUser.getUid());
        chatRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    chatRef1.child("id").setValue(fUser.getUid());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }

        });
```

and this code for determine what messages are unread:

```
 reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //fix
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
                int unread = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot1.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && !chat.isIsseen()){
                        unread++;
                    }
                }
                if(unread == 0 ){
                    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment() , "Chats");
                    
                }else {
                    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment() , "("+unread+") Chats");
             
                }
                viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UsersFragment(), "Users");
                viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

this is a snippet of my `ChatFragment` (where I have all the chats):

```
private List<Chatlist> usersList;
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
       recyclerView.hideIfEmpty(recyclerView);
       recyclerView.showIfEmpty(mEmptyView);
       fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
       usersList = new ArrayList<>();
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser.getUid());
       reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                usersList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chatlist chatlist = snapshot1.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                    usersList.add(chatlist);
                }
                chatList();
           }
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
           {
           }
       });
 private void chatList() {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                    for(Chatlist chatlist : usersList){
                        if(user.getId().equals(chatlist.getId())){
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
               usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getContext(), mUsers , true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort messages from realtime database by doing this:

```
myRef.orderByChild("timestamp").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener{
 /*Note that you need to implement the methods.
   For example: onChildAdded, onChildChanged etc.*/
})
```

Using **ChildEventListener** instead of **ValueEventListener**, will sort the children of every branch of your reference, example:

```
foo----
      |-branch1---|
      |           |-timestamp: "1234"
      |
      |
      |-branch2---|
                  |-timestamp: "2345"
```

With `DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("foo");` , `ChildEventListener`, and `orderByChild()`, like I showed You right before, the query will sort timestamps ordering them!

then if your new message still on the bottom and you want to swap the order, you can use on your **RecyclerView**:

```
recyclerView.setStackFromEnd(true)
reciclerView.setReverseLayout(true)
```

Hope it helps, happy coding! :)

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer, how is it going to be ordered by time in the code you provided? also where exactly should I add this part? in the send button?

Comment: You use a RecyclerView, right? well, when you populate the list with the snapshots from the realtime database server, you can use orderByChild() and onChildEventListener . Remember as well that you don't need to reference the child of your DatabaseReference, because it will skip automatically one child, like I explained in the answer!

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: yes I'm using a recycle view. ok I will try implementing this and I will let you know if it doesn't work

Comment: I'll be here to help in case! :)

Comment: thank you that's so nice of you. I have a question; this method should be implemented in the userAdapter or in the Fragment itself? and you said that orderByChild() will order the time so what is left to do? I mean will this fix the issue even if I left the method itself empty?

Comment: You should implement this method in the fragment, where you pass the data in the RecyclerView List. orderBychild() will sort childs by timestamp, so they will be sorted by the time they were created!

onChildAdded will call when you connect the first time the reference to the server and every time a new Child is added.

onChildChanged will call every time a child is modified, for example if you change only the timestamp!

For now, take all the code that you used in onDataChange and put it in onChildAdded when you'll swap the listener, then you will modify the code for what you need!

Comment: Example: if you want to sort "Chats" in your server, you want to do this: DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats"). Then you will add the onChildEventListener with the methods and the orderByChild("timestamp") and they will be sorted by timestamp value.

Comment: Thank you for explaining I hope it works as needed.  orderByChild("timestamp")  the time is saved in Firebase as "time", so I think I must use orderByChild("time") is that correct or should I use the value "timestamp" is it predefined?

Comment: You're welcome! Exactly, in this case you'll need to use orderByChild("time"), because you stored it with that key value! let me know if it works!

Comment: Hello again, sorry I know I bothered you. I edited the question and added the code of my fragment, maybe it will help you or others to understand my app more. I'm having a hard time coding the part "making one specific user above others". for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: It is hard for me to understand exactly how to help because i don't know how you stored the data on the server, the best hint I can give you is to simplify everything and keep simple! 

However let me know if you still need help!

Comment: ok, I will try my best, hopefully, eventually it will work and I will accept your answer for sure. Thanks a lot. can I mention you to another question I posted ? it is much simpler than this maybe you could help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376021/how-to-refer-to-bottom-navigation-bar-from-other-activites here is the link to the post